# How can I check if an image is sepia?

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, python-imaging-library

There are a lot of posts that look at how to convert an image *TO* sepia, but I'm trying to figure out how to detect if an image *ALREADY IS* sepia (without obviously training an ML model for simple classification).

I tried writing a function for mono chromaticism, but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```py
pic = Image.open(file)

pixel_values = list(pic.getdata())

for subpixels in pixel_values:
            if abs(subpixels[0] - subpixels[1]) < 50 and abs(subpixels [1] - subpixels [2]) < 50 and abs(subpixels[0] - subpixels[2]) < 50:
                count += 1
            else:
                pass

if count / len(subpixels) > .5:
            print('is chromatic')
```

Comment: How would you *define* "sepia"?

Comment: @ScottHunter Sepia by definition is `(112, 66, 20)` RGB. But I doubt that is of much help here.

Comment: Use HSV or HSL, check if hue is within some range. You will need some tweaking to disregard near-grayscale values as they might have any hue. (This also works for self-implemented greenscreen. :D But of course for green hues, not brownish colours = reddish and orangish hues.)

Comment: Just measure the color difference, such as rmse or just the average of the channel differences, between your defined sepia values and the average color of the image. See definition of rmse at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square. rmse = sort ( ((r1-r2)^2 + (g1-g2)^ + (b1-b2)^2)/3 ). Where r1=112, g1=66, b1=20 and r2 = mean of red channel of image, g2 is mean of green channel and b2 is mean of blue channel. Then set a threshold for how small you consider the rmse value to be to consider the image sepia colored.

Answer (score 3):

I'd stick to the idea using the HSV colorspace to identify regions with sepia like colors – as also mentioned in one of the comments. Nevertheless, I'd do the processing using [NumPy](https://numpy.org) and [OpenCV](https://opencv.org), since array-wise operations are much faster than iterating pixels in Pillow (PIL).

So, that'd be my solution:

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Calculate "sepia mask" using HSV color space; empirically set parameters
def sepia_mask(img):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    sepia_lower = np.array([np.round( 30 / 2), np.round(0.10 * 255), np.round(0.10 * 255)])
    sepia_upper = np.array([np.round( 45 / 2), np.round(0.60 * 255), np.round(0.90 * 255)])
    return cv2.inRange(hsv, sepia_lower, sepia_upper)

# "Sepia kernel" for filtering; https://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/03/24/sepia-filter-opencv/
sepia_kernel = np.array([
    [0.272, 0.534, 0.131],
    [0.349, 0.686, 0.168],
    [0.393, 0.769, 0.189]])

# Read image via Pillow; processing using OpenCV; sepia filtering
image_pil = Image.open('path/to/your/image.png')
image = np.flip(np.array(image_pil), 2)
sepia = cv2.transform(image, sepia_kernel)

# Outputs and sepia percentages
plt.figure(1, figsize=(9, 9))
plt.subplot(2, 2, 1), plt.imshow(np.flip(image, 2)), plt.title('Original image')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 2), plt.imshow(sepia_mask(image), cmap='gray')
perc = cv2.countNonZero(sepia_mask(image)) / np.prod(image.shape[:2])
plt.title('Sepia mask [' + str(perc) + ']')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 3), plt.imshow(np.flip(sepia, 2)), plt.title('Sepia filtered image')
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4), plt.imshow(sepia_mask(sepia), cmap='gray')
perc = cv2.countNonZero(sepia_mask(sepia)) / np.prod(sepia.shape[:2])
plt.title('Sepia mask [' + str(perc) + ']')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here's some exemplary output:

[image: Output]

Depending on the actual "sepia" you want to detect, you'll need to adapt the parameters in the `sepia_mask` method. As you can see, I calculated some "sepia percentages". Set up some cut-off for a classification sepia / non-sepia.

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
Matplotlib:  3.2.0rc1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.1.2
Pillow:      7.0.0
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to measure how much sepia color is in an image in Python/OpenCV. Simply get the mean color of the image and then get the different between the mean and your sepia defined color. This does not measure spatially how many pixels are sepia toned as in the method below by HansHirse. It simply measures overall color difference.

Image 1 (sepia toned):

[image]

Image 2 (blue toned):

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read images
img1 = cv2.imread('bear_sepia.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('bear_blue.png')

# compute mean color
mean1 = np.mean(img1, axis=(0,1))
mean2 = np.mean(img2, axis=(0,1))

print("img1_mean =",mean1)
print("img2_mean =",mean2)

# define sepia color
sepia = (20,66,112)

# compute inverse root mean squared difference as percent
# 100 is pure sepia color
inv_rmse1 = 100.0 * (1 - np.sqrt( ((mean1[0] - sepia[0])**2 + (mean1[1] - sepia[1])**2 + (mean1[2] - sepia[2])**2)/3 ) / 255.0)
inv_rmse2 = 100.0 * (1 - np.sqrt( ((mean2[0] - sepia[0])**2 + (mean2[1] - sepia[1])**2 + (mean2[2] - sepia[2])**2)/3 ) / 255.0)

print("percent_sepia_img1 =",inv_rmse1)
print("percent_sepia_img2 =",inv_rmse2)

cv2.imshow('img1', img1)
cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Results:

```
img1_mean = [ 54.11960236  84.72731845 115.33092206]
img2_mean = [200.27158686  76.78135771  76.78135771]

percent_sepia_img1 = 91.15556648084234
percent_sepia_img2 = 58.34117845977803
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer: an image can have the same mean color as the "sepia color", but it doesn't mean it's sepia filtered